# How to create E-commerce Application in PHP?

Tags: php, e-commerce

i am new to PHP, i want to make a small E-Commerce Application in PHP.Although I have developed a non E-commerce based apps in PHP, But Don't know about E-Commerce based App.

Please help me from where i have to start .
Or what is new stuff to learn to create a PHP E-Commerce App.

Comment: try `CRE LOADED` `JOOMLA` OR `SYMFONY` Framework

Comment: lots of nice open source ones to modify, much safer than starting from scratch

Comment: If you love the Laravel Framework why don't you try: AvoRed E-commerce its under development but still a great way to start. https://github.com/avored/laravel-ecommerce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of free, opensource e-commerce applications available like, [Opencart](http://www.opencart.com/)
, [Prestashop](http://www.prestashop.com/), etc. If you know wordpress you can also check for e-commerce plugins for wordpress. [Wp-Commerce](http://www.instinct.co.nz/e-commerce/) is a good one as far as I know